# How to prune math operation with case'd operand in bash?

Tags: bash, optimization

This is the working code:

```
nn=2
((nn += `
  case "2" in
  "1") printf 5 ;;
  "2") printf 10 ;;
  *)   printf 20 ;;
  esac
`))
echo $nn
```

How I can to simplify like this:

```
nn=2
((nn += `
  case "2" in
  "1") 5 ;;
  "2") 10 ;;
  *)   20 ;;
  esac
`))
echo $nn
```

I know that can be done in the body of each case. ( ((nn += 5)) ... ((nn += 10)) ... e.t.c.)
But its advisable to keep the first's structures.

Comment: if you *must* use `case`, you're pretty much condemned to use commands  after the pattern, and though it's conceivably possible to make those numbers into commands, that's not very maintainable or readable. you could replace the `printf`s with the builtin `echo`.

Comment: `echo` works but I guess you don't want that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what this is doing there:

> case "2" in

... if it's like that the optimization is to get rid of the `case`. But I guess it's just a mistake in your example.

Anyway, how about writing like this:

```
case "$1" in
    1) m=5 ;;
    2) m=10 ;;
    *) m=20 ;;
esac
((nn += m))
echo $nn
```

You wrote you want "to keep the first's structures". I guess you meant to not duplicate the operation on `nn`. By rewriting this way, the operation on `nn` is in one place, and the `case` statement changes the operands, so I think it should answer your need. It's also a more natural way of writing `bash` scripts than putting there a backtick expansion.

Comment: good answer, +1, an approach I didn't think of, having the command be a variable assignment. about as clean a use of `case` as I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind not using `case`, which requires *commands* after the patterns, and if your version of Bash supports associative arrays, you could do [updated as per comment]:

```
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ cat /tmp/test.sh; echo ---; bash /tmp/test.sh
declare -A values=([abc]=0 [111]=5 [fff]=10); default=20
function add() {
 number=$1; index=$2; 
 echo $(($number + ${values[$index]:-$default}))
}
for test in 123 abc n 111 abz fff; do echo 2+values[$test]=$(add 2 $test); done
---
2+values[123]=22
2+values[abc]=2
2+values[n]=22
2+values[111]=7
2+values[abz]=22
2+values[fff]=12
```

note that when I first made this modification, for some reason my version of Bash was showing strange behavior, possibly due to my not `declare`ing the array. except for the first test, the default used is 10, the last assigned element of the array, and it used that default for array element abc whose value is 0. something to watch out for, perhaps I'll look into this more some day:

```
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ cat /tmp/test.sh; echo ---; bash /tmp/test.sh
function add() {
 number=$1; index=$2; values=([abc]=0 [111]=5 [fff]=10); default=20
 echo $(($number + ${values[$index]-$default}))
}
for test in 123 abc n 111 abz fff; do echo 2+values[$test]=$(add 2 $test); done
---
2+values[123]=22
2+values[abc]=12
2+values[n]=12
2+values[111]=7
2+values[abz]=12
2+values[fff]=12
```

note also that in the updated example above I moved the static values outside of the subroutine, as it probably makes more sense to have them be global for the script.

Comment: Thank you! I did not say that I need string patterns. Not "1", "2". But "abc" "111" "fff".